# Firebase billing turn off puppeteer cloud functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, puppeteer

My question consists two parts

1. What if I turn off Firebase billing and switch to spark plan will all cloud functions will be deleted?
2. Can I turn off billing using cloud functions and puppeteer to prevent myself from attack?

Answer (score 1):

1. According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/billing/firebase-pricing-plans#downgrade-blaze-to-spark), your data is not getting deleted but your project loses access to paid features.
2. There is an example of how to stop billing using Cloud Functions described in the [automated cost control responses guide](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/notify#write-a-cloud-function-2).

Comment: But using pubsub turn off cap is dangerous because it will also end my project free tier and may delete my data, also due to latency it may take days to execute which is not good

Comment: @Noobdeveloper You are right. I think it's safer to [set a budget](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/budgets#add-new-budget) and use billing alerts in order to control expenditure.